# Vs code change property to jsx attribute

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsx

[image]

the code in the video i watched:

[image]

When it hovers, my code looks like property and in his code, it looks like a JSX attribute. what is the reason of this ? How can I convert it to jsx attribute? I would be glad if you help

Comment: Dumb question: are you sure he's using visual studio code and not webstorm or another editor?

Comment: I'm sure. It's writing visual studio code.